# connect to azure sql server through datacenter ip address

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-sql-server

I trying connect to azure sql server (xxxx.database.windows.net) through datacenter ip addres, i changed connect policy by proxy, but now i don't know how connect to instance the sql server.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-connectivity-architecture

Answer (score 0):

You may have to add the datacenter IP range as a rule on the Azure SQL Database firewall rule. Please download and read [this](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=41653) document to know the current IP range of the datacenter where your database resides.

Alternatively you can also set "Allow Access to Azure Services" to On (see image below), although this option configures the firewall to allow all connections from Azure including connections from the subscriptions of other customers.

[image]

In addition to configure the firewall, for security reasons make sure your login and user permissions limit access to only authorized users.

[This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-connect-query-ssms) guide may provide you additional valuable information to connect to your Azure SQL databases.

Comment: Looking at the IP range list of the data center, I do not see the region of
south central us, I also observe a large number of ip's. Should I attach all the corresponding ones to my region?

at the end of all this process I seek to connect to my azure database through the own ip of the datacenter

Comment: You should add all the IP because a SQL Server endpoint could associated with any IP. As you can see on this link, the feature of allowing access by region has been requested by another Azure customer before and you can vote for it https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217321-sql-database/suggestions/35186611-allow-acces-to-azure-services-by-region